# schema.rb crashes for enum type in postgres

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, enums

I am using `gender` field of my `user` table as `enum` type.

Migration also runs sucessfully. But the schema.rb get crashes.

After running the migration, my `schema.rb` looks:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 2018_07_23_115046) do

    # These are extensions that must be enabled in order to support this database
    enable_extension "plpgsql"

    # Could not dump table "users" because of following StandardError
    # Unknown type 'gender' for column 'gender'

end
```

my migration is:

```
class AddGenderToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def up
    execute <<-SQL
      CREATE TYPE gender AS ENUM ('male', 'female', 'not_sure', 'prefer_not_to_disclose');
    SQL

    add_column :users, :gender, :gender, index: true
  end

  def down
    remove_column :users, :gender

    execute <<-SQL
      DROP TYPE gender;
    SQL
  end
end
```

I don't understand why the `schema.rb` crashes.

Comment: `Unknown type 'gender' for column 'gender'`

Comment: you should better not to create a type, but store those as an integer, then add a `enum gender: { male: 0, female: 1, not_sure: 2, prefer_not_to_disclose: 3 }
` line to your model class. this will provide you all functionality on application layer which you expect from database. btw [according to the guides](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_postgresql.html#enumerated-types) declaring an enumerated gender type has zero benefit. they are stored as normal text columns. 

[btw this might be useful](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Postgres custom types aren't supported by "Ruby-style" schemas. In order to use this functionality, you'll need to switch to a SQL-formatted schema. Switch the value of `config.active_record.schema_format` in `config/application.rb` to `:sql`.

Comment: I am using rails 5.2 and after adding the line `config.active_record.schema_format = :sql` in `config/application.rb`. The problem remains. I also did the `rails db:reset`.

Comment: @SourabhBanka do you now have a file named `db/structure.sql`? Your schema should be stored in there from now on. If you do see that, you can safely delete `schema.rb`, it's no longer being used by Rails.

Answer (score 0):

#### Custom enum types in PostgreSQL (Rails 7+)

`schema.rb` is crashing since Rails had no built-in support for custom enum types in PostgreSQL.

Starting from Rails 7, a new [create_enum](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/PostgreSQLAdapter.html#method-i-create_enum) method is introduced that allows to write migrations like so:

```rb
# db/migrate/20131220144913_create_articles.rb
def up
  create_enum :article_status, ["draft", "published"]

  create_table :articles do |t|
    t.enum :status, enum_type: :article_status, default: "draft", null: false
  end
end

# There's no built in support for dropping enums, but you can do it manually.
# You should first drop any table that depends on them.
def down
  drop_table :articles

  execute <<-SQL
    DROP TYPE article_status;
  SQL
end
```

This way `schema.rb` will be updated automatically and there is no need to change `config.active_record.schema_format` to `sql` (at least for this particular case).

**Sources**:

- [Pull Request](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/41469).
- [Rails Guides](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_postgresql.html#enumerated-types).
- [Rails API](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/PostgreSQLAdapter.html#method-i-create_enum).
- [Rails 7 adds better support for custom enum types in PostgreSQL](https://blog.saeloun.com/2022/01/12/rails-7-adds-custom-enum-support-in-postgresql) by [Saeloun](https://blog.saeloun.com/).